# Resize site width to fit within width of iPad screen

Tags: ios, ipad, css

I have a site that is 2048px wide.  Is there a way to automatically have the iPad fit the entire site width on the screen when the site is loaded?  I've tried experimenting with meta viewport in a few different ways:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
```

This hasn't worked though.  The site is still too wide and spills off screen on the iPad.

Comment: Make sure to use commas to separate e.g. `width=device-width` and `maximum-scale=1.0`.

Comment: Thanks. Still no dice though.

Comment: These viewport attributes will mean that Safari allow responsive design to work, rather than zoom the page out to allow the entire width to be visible on the iPad screen. What they won't do is override CSS styles applied to the page - if the wrapper or body have a fixed width it won't change that. Try using Adobe Edge Inspect http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/ to see what styles are being applied on the iPad. Include the wrapper CSS styles in your question if you can.

Comment: I want to zoom the page out to allow the entire width to be visible on the iPad screen though.  How would I accomplish that?

Comment: AFAIK Safari on iOS will do this by default, unless you have these meta tags. The disadvantage of this is that by zooming out, users often have to zoom and scroll to navigate around the page. The width meta tag overrides this default behaviour to allow use of Responsive Design (http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), where specific CSS style properties are applied at or between specific widths. A key part of Responsive Web Design is use of percentages rather than fixed widths, adapting layout using specific rules as the viewport resizes and content "breaks". Key, use percentages.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a fixed size to the content width like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=2048" />
```

May need some tweaking to allow for padding either side, but should load the site at that size and allow users to zoom in.

Answer (score 1):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

That's what I use for my website.

Comment: Can you provide a live example? **Edit:** Does this site work on your iPad: https://v1k.org/ ?

Comment: You can check my HTML source. I just use the meta code provided in my answer. Do you mind giving me a link to your site?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately can't as it's a protected client site.

Comment: I had minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0. Then I Added initial-scale=1.0 and worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to fix this problem are by using percentages rather than fixed widths. But if you "cannot" change that, you can force your viewport to scale down by using 0.x in initial-scale like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.625, user-scalable=yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-width: 2048px;` to the html and body tags in css.  That's fixed some weirdness on iPads for me before, but not sure if it will apply to this one.

Comment: Unless this website is designed solely for use on large screen devices, this approach will cause substantial usability issues (and lots of scrolling) on devices with smaller screens - especially mobile. Consider Responsive Web Design (http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) to allow your site content to adapt to varying viewport sizes, or use a width representative of most visitors to your site (use something like Google Analytics to determine this) if you have to use fixed width. Forcing a very high or low width for all users will provide a bad user experience for many.

Comment: His site width is 2048... I think usability is already an issue.  I don't think setting the width will escalate things.  Responsive is always a better answer, but that's not what he asked.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a site with the same problem recently, it wouldn't stay zoomed out between page clicks for a fixed 960px width site.  Try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=-100%" />
```

So far so good, passed on my Ipad Air.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```